# mix list<string> in c#

Tags: c#, list

i have a 4 list in c# how i can make a list from them. means to say make a list from the result of 4 list.

Comment: Do you want them just concatenated together? The union avoiding duplicates? The intersection of common elements of the 4 lists? We need more details in order to provide meaningful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the List constructor to achieve this.

Something like

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();

...

List<string> concat = new List<string> (list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear, but I *suspect* you mean something like:

```
List<List<string>> stringLists = ...;

// SelectMany is a "flattening" operation
List<string> singleList = stringLists.SelectMany(list => list).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28VS.80%29.aspx) to add one list to another.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "rabbit", "hat" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "frog", "pond" };
list2.InsertRange(0, list1);
```